# Using replace in R multiple times in function

Tags: r, function, replace

I'm trying to use R's replace multiple times in a function, but only the last use seems to work. For instance, using x where

```
x <- c(1:3)
```

if I wanted to add one to each odd value, I tried

```
test <- function(x) {
replace(x,x==1,2)
replace(x,x==3,4)
}
```

but test(x) results in (1,2,4) where I wanted it to be (2,2,4)--in other words, only the last "replace" seems to be working. I know I could refer to the values by location within the vector, but anyone know how to fix this if I want to refer to the values themselves?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Try: `x = ifelse(x%%2!=0, x+1, x)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to assign the output of the replace function to a variable

```
x <- c(1:3) 
test <- function(x) {
  x <- replace(x,x==1,2)
  replace(x,x==3,4)
}
test(x)
[1] 2 2 4
```

Or using the `case_when` function from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
case_when(x == 1 ~ 2,
          x == 3 ~ 4, 
          TRUE ~ as.double(x))
[1] 2 2 4
```